# MPMoviePlayerController problem with setting the currentPlaybackTime property

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm streaming (progressively downloading, to be precise) a mp3 file over the net using MPMoviePlayerController. The user can control the playback through a UISlider.

But when I try so set the moviePlayer.currentPlaybackTime, nothing happens! I do checks to see if the time i try to seek to is within the playableDuration range.

I have tried to pause the playback before I change the property and playing immediately after but the sound just hicups and then continues as nothing happened.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I'm understanding the question exactly as you mean it; however, if you do the following I'm able in code that I have to advance to the proper place (closest to the nearest frame) in a video.

```
[player stop];
[player setInitialPlaybackTime:xx.xx];
[player play];
```

Comment: This will cut off the footage. You won't be able to seek to a point before `xx.xx`.